# can't put my code in oncreate function

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have one imageview which should be on the left of screen and when I click on, it will come to the center of screen
when I put the code in **OnCreate** function the app doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public void fadeFunction  (View view){
    ImageView patrick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patrick);
    patrick.animate().translationXBy(1500f).setDuration(2000);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageView patrick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patrick);//my code here
    patrick.setTranslationX(-1500f);//my code here
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the following two lines down to somewhere *after* `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`:

```
ImageView patrick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patrick);//my code here
patrick.setTranslationX(-1500f);//my code here
```

The result should be something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView patrick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patrick);//my code here
    patrick.setTranslationX(-1500f);//my code here
    // ... other code code goes here
}
```

The reason for this is that you simply cannot perform the view lookup *before* you've defined the layout to look it up in. Well, syntactically you can, but it will always return `null`;

Answer (score 2):

`setContentView()` is what tells your Activity to take a layout XML file and instantiate the Views defined there.

If you try to access your Views before that (e.g. with `ImageView patrick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patrick);`), you will find that your Views don't exist yet.

Moving your code below `setContentView()` like so will resolve that particular issue.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ImageView patrick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patrick);//my code here
patrick.setTranslationX(-1500f);//my code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call **findViewById()** **after** the call to **setContentView()**. So make the following change to your code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView patrick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patrick);//my code here
    patrick.setTranslationX(-1500f);//my code here
}
```